# Can we find a table that is used in a set of FMBs without opening it individually in Oracle Forms?

Tags: oracle, search, oracleforms, lov

I am using both Oracle Forms version 11g and 12c.

Is it possible to find a table for e.g table1 used in the Oracle Forms application screens including LOV's without opening each FMB individually and searching in it.

Totally there are around 50-75 FMBs in the application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While Forms was a new software product, back then in its 3.0 version (or even lower), you could choose whether you'll keep the form *source*

- in the database or

  - in that case, you could have written a query which selects data from the data dictionary and - hopefully - extract tables' names
- in file system

  - file extension was .INP (not .FMB) and it was a **textual** file; it means that you could even create a form using text editor! Nobody probably did that, but hey - you could have done it.

.FMB is no longer textual file. Yes, you can open it it a text editor (such as Notepad++) and **search** for e.g. `FROM` (because any table used in form's PL/SQL units or LoVs is part of a `SELECT` statement which requires the `FROM` keyword) and get something like this:

[image]

Yes, you'll get "duplicates" if any table is referenced more than once.

---

Another option is to write a program which will parse the .FMB file and extract tables' names (I can't help with that, though).

Comment: I don't think this will help find tables that are used as the base table for a block, though.

Comment: It won't, @Andy. In my opinion, it is probably better to visit all forms and extract data from them than *browsing* through binary files of any kind. It *is* boring, but hey - what has to be done, has to be done.